# Golang: how to specify certificate in TLS config for http client

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I have a cert file, that location is: `/usr/abc/my.crt` and I want to use that cert for my tls config, so that my http client uses that certificate when communicate with other servers. My current code is as follows:

```
mTLSConfig := &tls.Config {
    CipherSuites: []uint16 {
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    }
}

mTLSConfig.PreferServerCipherSuites = true
mTLSConfig.MinVersion = tls.VersionTLS10
mTLSConfig.MaxVersion = tls.VersionTLS10

tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: mTLSConfig,
}

c := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

So how to assign a certificate in my TLS config? I see the certificate settings at http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config can someone suggest how to config my cert location there?

`mTLSConfig.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{'/usr/abc/my.crt'}}` <-- is wrong because I am passing string.right? I DON'T have ANY other files such as .pem or .key etc, just only this my.cert. I am blank how to do it?

Earlier, I had edited the go source code http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/x509/root_unix.go  and added `/usr/abc/my.crt` after line no. 12 and it worked. But the problem is my certificate file location can change, so I have removed the hardcoded line from root_unix.go and trying to pass it dynamically, when building TLSConfig.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can replace the system CA set by providing a root CA pool in tls.Config.

```
certs := x509.NewCertPool()

pemData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pemPath)
if err != nil {
    // do error
}
certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemData)
mTLSConfig.RootCAs = certs
```

If you still want the system's roots however, I think you'll need to recreate the functionality in `initSystemRoots()`. I don't see any exposed method for merging a cert into the default system roots.

Comment: Thank @JimB , but this does not solve the problem. As you are sugegsting to pass pemData, while I have file path. I stumbled upon https://gist.github.com/spikebike/2232102 but there it is using LoadX509KeyPair while I have ONLY ONE cert file

Comment: @JVK I don't understand your comment. I'll add some code to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, this is the simplest way to use a pem file. Do we have any method to use a pass-phrase along with this?

Comment: @Manu: I don't understand. This answer is about adding a CA. There's no private key involved, so you don't need a passphrase.

Comment: Sorry if I am writing in a wrong context.
I was tring to connect to apple push notification service with a pem file.
My code look likes below. I have to use a passphrase along with the pem file.

`certs := x509.NewCertPool()
    pemData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("pemfile.pem")
    if err != nil {
 // do error
   }
   certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemData)
   mTLSConfig.ClientCAs = certs

   cacerts := x509.NewCertPool()
   pemData2, err := ioutil.ReadFile("cacertificate.pem")
   if err != nil {
 // do error
   }
   cacerts.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemData2)
   mTLSConfig.RootCAs = cacerts
`

Comment: @Manu: that's not related to this question and answer, and I can't read your code or answer sufficiently in comments. Please create a new question if you need to.

Comment: @JimB Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714397/go-tls-connection-to-apple-push-notification-server-is-not-working