# How to specify custom SSL roots with Go on Linux

Tags: linux, go, ssl-certificate, x509

Suppose I'm using a third party network library that I don't want to modify. It uses the standard `http.Request` interface to make some HTTPS requests.

I'm running it on an embedded Linux instance that doesn't have a certificate roots installed, and the only directory I can access is `/data`. This means you get the error:

```
Get https://example.com/: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided
```

Is there any way to actually *provide* roots? As far as I can tell [Go looks in these directories for X509 certificate roots](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go) ([see also](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_unix.go)):

```
var certFiles = []string{
    "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", // Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo etc.
    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",   // Fedora/RHEL
    "/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem",             // OpenSUSE
    "/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem",            // OpenELEC
}
var certDirectories = []string{
    "/system/etc/security/cacerts", // Android
}
```

As I said, I don't have access to those, and the [root pool seems to be private](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root.go) so you can't append to it:

```
var (
    once        sync.Once
    systemRoots *CertPool
)
func systemRootsPool() *CertPool {
    once.Do(initSystemRoots)
    return systemRoots
}
```

Is this just impossible with Go?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562269/golang-how-to-specify-certificate-in-tls-config-for-http-client

Comment: No, they specify a new root pool that they use with a custom `http.Client`. They don't replace the system roots. However I have found another way (answer in a minute...)

Comment: you don't need to replace `systemRoots`, it's only providing a default. What can't you do with with a custom `tls.Config` and your own `RootCAs`.

Comment: The key was `http.DefaultTransport.TLSClientConfig`. The other question doesn't mention it. (This isn't a duplicate; I don't know why you marked it as such.)

Comment: Sorry, It seemed you were having trouble creating the tls.Config with custom RootCAs, and assigning it to the default was the obvious part.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to work (I actually only need one certificate chain, which you can get from Firefox easily by clicking on the SSL lock icon, More Information, View Certificate, Details, Export, Change type to "X509 certificate with chain (PEM)".

```
func initCerts() error {
    certs := x509.NewCertPool()
    pemData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("api.example.crt")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemData)

    newTlsConfig := &tls.Config{}
    newTlsConfig.RootCAs = certs

    defaultTransport := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    defaultTransport.TLSClientConfig = newTlsConfig
    return nil
}
```

I'm not certain, but the docs suggest that you must do that before using any TLS functions, so I put it at the start of my `main()`.

Comment: You doesn't affect any tls functions, you're assigning something in the http package. You do need to assign this before you use http.DefaultTransport, which is used by any http.Client with no Transport defined.